# How to use two variable types in a pydantic.BaseModel with typing.Union?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I need my model to accept either a bytes type variable or a string type variable and to raise an exception if any other type was passed.

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: Union[bytes, str]


m1 = MyModel(a='123')
m2 = MyModel(a=b'123')

print(type(m1.a))
print(type(m2.a))
```

In my case the model interprets both bytes and string as bytes.

Output:

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

Desired output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

The desired output above can be achieved if I re-assign member a:

```py
m1 = MyModel(a='123')
m1.a = '123'
```

Is it possible to get it in one go?

Comment: Just a slight inconsistency in your code. If you define `Foo.a` as `Union[bytes, str]` your output should be `<class 'bytes'>` for both. Instead to get `<class 'str'>` for both you would need `Union[str, bytes]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the `str` type does some automatic conversions ([here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#standard-library-types) in the docs):

> strings are accepted as-is, `int` `float` and `Decimal` are coerced using `str(v)`, `bytes` and `bytearray` are converted using `v.decode()`, enums inheriting from `str` are converted using `v.value`, and all other types cause an error

> `bytes` are accepted as-is, `bytearray` is converted using `bytes(v)`, `str` are converted using `v.encode()`, and `int`, `float`, and `Decimal` are coerced using `str(v).encode()`

You can use [`StrictTypes`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#strict-types) to avoid automatic conversion between compatible types (e.g.: `str` and `bytes`):

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr, StrictBytes


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: Union[StrictStr, StrictBytes]


m1 = MyModel(a='123')
m2 = MyModel(a=b'123')

print(type(m1.a))
print(type(m2.a))
```

Output will be as expected:

```py
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
```